# How to wait for a website to load the elements's xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath

I would like in my javascript program to be able to start searching for certain elements on a web-page by their xpath.
I want to do that as fast as possible so that means that as soon as the page is loaded I want to locate the element.

I have tried to wait for the DOM of the web-page to be loaded, unofortunately you can only access the id's at that moment and no xpath.

For the moment I am using

```
window.onload = function() {
//start searching for element
}
```

This is very slow especially for websites where there are a lot of images and others because it waits for the full website to be loaded

I would like to know (if it is even possible) how to wait only for the xpath of the elements to be ready and to start searching at that moment.

Comment: Note that we don't use [solved] devices here - there is a proper acceptance system, as you have discovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the DOM elements are parsed and ready for access when the [`window.DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event fires. The `load` event fires later, after all the external resources have finished downloading.

In the code below, you'll note that `Parsed` appears before `Loaded` in the console:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 console.log("Parsed");
});

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
 console.log("Loaded");
});
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1608a.jpg">
```

UPDATE:

Based on your comment below, I have put together what your code would look like:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 // Invoke your custom mouse event function. You need to determine
 // how the element name will be gotten. Here, I am asking the user
 // to supply an element name (div, p, h1, span, etc.)
 setupMouseEvent(prompt("Enter an element name."));
});

function setupMouseEvent(elementName){
  // Locate the first element that matches the name supplied in the parameter
  // Don't use .getElementsByName()[0] to get the first match - 
  // that's very inefficient and uses an outdated API that returns
  // a live node list.  Also, no quotes or concatenation is used here.
  var cb = document.querySelector(elementName);
  
  // The event code below will dispatch a click event for the element
  // but if you don't have a click event handler set up for the element
  // then you won't be able to react to the event.
  cb.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(this.nodeName + " was clicked.");
  });
 
  // While the following does set up a click mouse event,
  // I'm not sure why you are bothering with it. You could just
  // call cb.click() to dispatch the existing click event.
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', { 
    view: window, 
    bubbles: true, 
    cancelable: true 
  });
 
  cb.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```html
<div>Some Element</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your method using 
   "window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ ... }); "
with my script :
   "var event = new MouseEvent('click', { view: window, bubbles: true, 
   cancelable: true }); var cb = document.getElementsByName('" + 
   elementName + "')[0]; cb.dispatchEvent(event);"
which allows me to click a webelement using it's XPath. However, even though the script works just fine when I run it alone, once incorporated inside the brackets of the code you gave me, it doesn't work anymore(it does nothing). 
Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @abiday I've updated my answer to incorporate your code, but you have errors in that code and I'm not even sure what you are trying to accomplish with it since elements already have `click` events and all you need to do to trigger that is call the `clickI()` method on the element. Also, you are not using XPath at all here. XPath is a query language with its own syntax and is used on XML document structures. See my comments in the code for more.

Comment: Actually I have created another method that clicks on elements based on their 'name' property and I wrongly sent this method instead of the one that is using 'xpath' but my xpath method works essentially the same way. Also it is true that the way you click on elements is way easier and seems to be also more efficient. So I am definitely going to implement it in my code.

Comment: Anyways thank you very much for your time and your help !

Comment: @abiday I'd be interested to see your "XPath" code because XPath is for XML, not HTML (are you using XHTML?) and it requires the use of an XML parser to work.

Comment: here is my code : document.evaluate('" + elementXpath + "', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));

Comment: @abiday what is the point of using this technique here? All you are doing is saying find me the first instance of the specified element within the document, which is much more simply done with `document.querySelector(element)`. Again, an HTML document isn't an XML document, so using XPath on it is inappropriate.

Comment: Indead you are right I was doing it before but now I have adapted the code to use querySelector